# Shaving Charactors off filenames

Tags: command-line, regex

I have some files. I would like to trim few characters from their filenames. The characters could be on the head or tail. It does not need to be a single command to shave them all.

Two examples are:

- From a file `01 - SongTitle.mp3` want to strip away `01 -`
- From another file `SongTitle - ArtistName.mp3` want to strip away `- ArtistName`

If possible I would like a "string to be removed" and a "string to keep" type of implementation and not something so specific to these examples. I am willing to the the command a string to match and have "string to delete".

Comment: An example of the sort of filename and characters would be helpful.

Comment: [Edit] your question to add some example input and your desired output from those.

Comment: It's not clear what would be common portion to strip. From your examples, it seems you want to keep only `SongTitle`, but thats not generic presumably, and can happen to be present anywhere. We need complete list of possibilities.

Comment: It wouldn't happen anywhere and somethings have both, i would like to be able to change this myself instead of having a script for this one time. If something has both I can run two commands to solve that problem, I'm trying to get a generic solution. Is there a way to remove a string from a file name or remove N chars of a filename given a starting location and the number of char? Can you use negative indexes of the filename?

Comment: You can do this kind of thing in a one-liner using the perl based `rename`/`prename` command - for example `prename -vn 's/^\d+ - //' *.mp3` to remove a leading sequence of digits followed by space-hyhen-space or `prename -vn 's/ - [^.]*//' *.mp3` to remove a trailing space-hyphen-space followed by any characters up to the dot suffix. The difficulty is in making it both sufficiently specific and sufficiently general - if you ran the second one first, you'd end up with `01.mp3` since there's no way for `perl` to know that the `01` isn't a songtitle or that `SongTitle` isn't an artist name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Case - I

As you are looking to rename a file `01 - This is a song.mp3` to `This is a song.mp3` trimming `01 -` at the beginning. It can be done like this,

```
$ echo "01 - This is a song.mp3" | sed 's/^[0-9]* - //'
This is a song.mp3
```

### How it works:

- First identify the common part (two numbers at the beginning of the filename followed by a space, a hyphen and another space) that you want to replace from all the filenames here.
- Next we need a regexp for the common part.
- The caret `^` matches the position before the first character in a string and the character set `[0-9]` matches a single digit between 0 and 9.
- The asterisk `^[0-9]*` matches one or more digits between 0 and 9 at the beginning of string.
- So `^[0-9]* -` is our desired regexp which matches one or more digits between 0 and 9 at the beginning of string followed by a space, a hyphen and another space.

From `man sed`

```
s/regexp/replacement/
          Attempt to match regexp against the pattern space.  If successful, 
replace that  portion  matched  with replacement.
```

For example, try it in terminal

```
$ echo "Good day" | sed 's/day/night/'
Good night
$ echo "Good day" | sed 's/day//' ## replacement is kept blank
Good
```

- Let us look back to our original problem. We don't want the matched part to remain in the expression and replaced with blank using `sed`.

#### Case - II

The second set of files you want to rename from `This is a song - Some Artist.mp3` to `This is a song` trimming `- Some Artist` at the end. Try

```
$ echo "This is a song - Some Artist.mp3" | sed 's/ -.*/.mp3/'
This is a song.mp3
```

### How it works:

- First identify the strings to be replaced. Here it is the part of string starting from a space followed by a hyphen and the rest of the string. But we want the extension `.mp3` to be intact.
- Here my approach was to match the whole string after a space followed by a hyphen and replace that with `.mp3` so it remains in the string at the end of the string after replacement.
- The dot `.` matches a single character, without caring what that character is. The only exception is line break characters.
- `-.*` matches one or more any characters after a space and hyphen. Note that it will match `.mp3` as well.
- Hence using `sed` I have replaced the matching part with `.mp3`

you can learn more on regexp on the [regular-expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/quickstart.html)

---

#### A better regexp for case-II

This part I have lifted from [steeldriver](https://askubuntu.com/questions/828324/shaving-charactors-off-filenames/828384?noredirect=1#comment1260397_828324)

```
echo "This is a song - Some Artist.mp3" | sed 's/ -[^.]*//'
This is a song.mp3
```

### How it works:

- Here the approach is to match the part of string after a space followed by a hyphen before the dot `.` of `.mp3` and to replace the matching part with blank.
- `[^.]` matches any character but not a dot `.`
- Finally the regexp `-[^.]*` matches a space followed by a hyphen one or more any character but not a dot `.` or in other word before encountering a dot `.` which is our desired regexp.

---

### File renaming

#### Rename files using `sed` and `for` loop in bash shell

To rename files as described in case-I you can use:

```
for i in *.mp3; do mv "$i" "$(echo $i | sed 's/^[0-9]* - //')" ; done
```

To rename files as described in case-II you can use:

```
for i in *.mp3; do mv "$i" "$(echo $i | sed 's/ -.*/.mp3/')" ; done
```

#### A better alternative to avoid loop+sed using `rename`

```
rename -v 's/^[0-9]* - //' *.mp3  # For the first set
rename -v 's/ -.*/.mp3/' *.mp3   # For the second set
```

Comment: There is `rename` command for that instaead of loop+sed.

Comment: @Pilot6 I forgot about `rename` as I hardly use it. I will add it. Thank you for reminding.

Comment: It is `rename 's/^[0-9]* - //' *.mp3`

Comment: could you describe what s/^[0-9]* - // and  s/\ -.*/.mp3/ are saying in a character by character type of fashion. Something like "s/ does ... , ^ does ... , etc. I know that * is a many-wild and "\ " is a space, I gather the [0-9]* is any number of numbers but the things i dont understand are the 's/' and what the last two / in each line represent

Comment: @BenStumpf Please see the explanations in my edited answer. Hope everything is more meaningful now.